# How can I fix "Declaration or statement expected"?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So i'm a newbie, coded a discord bot and idk how to make it work since i had a lot of issues with it, some have been fixed but I can't get past this. The error is as mentioned above "Declaration or statement expected." or "Unexpected Token" (i tried make it work in 2 different softwares) at the *.play(queueConstruct.songs[0], message, client),* Now i'm stuck here. I'd appreciate if anyone could take their time and try to help me

This is the code:

```
const { play } = require("../include/play");
const { Client, Collection, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { attentionembed } = require("../util/attentionembed");
const {approveemoji,denyemoji,PREFIX,} = require(`../config.json`);
const ytsr = require("youtube-sr");

async execute(message, args, client) {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    const { channel } = message.member.voice;
    const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    if (!channel) return attentionembed(message, "Please join a Voice Channel first");
    if (serverQueue && channel !== message.guild.me.voice.channel)
      return attentionembed(message, `You must be in the same Voice Channel as me`);
    if (!args.length)
      return attentionembed(message, `Usage: ${message.client.prefix}play <YouTube URL or Video Name>`);
    //react with approve emoji
    message.react(approveemoji).catch(console.error);
    const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has("CONNECT"))
      return attentionembed(message, "I need permissions to join your channel!");
    if (!permissions.has("SPEAK"))
      return attentionembed(message, "I need permissions to speak in your channel");

//...//

    try {
      .play(queueConstruct.songs[0], message, client),
      catch (error) {
      //if an error comes log
      console.error(error);
      //delete the Queue
      message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
      //leave the channel
      await channel.leave();
      //sent an error message
      return attentionembed(message, `Could not join the channel: ${error}`); 
    }
  };
```

(idk if it helps but i've got the node v16.20.2)

I tried adding like a code above or upon the ".play(...)"

```
 
  let stream = null; 
      if (song.url.includes("youtube.com")) {

        stream = await ytdl(song.url);
  stream.on('error', function(er)  {
        if (er) {
          if (queue) {
          queue.songs.shift();
          play(queue.songs[0]);
        return sendError(`An unexpected error has occurred.\nPossible type \`${er}\``, message.channel)
            }
          }
      });
  }
      queue.connection.on("disconnect", () => message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id));

        const dispatcher = queue.connection
           .play(ytdl(song.url, {quality: 'highestaudio', highWaterMark: 1 << 25 ,type: "opus"}))
           .on("finish", () => {
             const shiffed = queue.songs.shift();
              if (queue.loop === true) {
                  queue.songs.push(shiffed);
              };
            play(queue.songs[0])
          })
```

And if i remember corectly it broke more or something like that, so i deleted it. I also removed the point before play, it gave me another error that i quite not remember what it had said so i let it as it was before.

Comment: Immediately inside of the `try` block you call `.play(...)`.  What is that supposed to do and why?  If there's a function called `play` then what is the `.` for?  If that function is on an object, where is that object?  That line is simply a syntax error.

Comment: Even more... That line is terminated with a comma, not a semi-colon.  Why?  And you don't close the `try` block before moving on to the `catch`.  Basically everything about those few lines of code is entirely broken.  It's not clear what the intent was supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the syntax error problem. Now my bot works perfectly, that was the only error I couldn't bring myself to resolve it somehow. Thanks so much!!